# Setting resque-Interval on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, resque

If I deploy to heroku and want to set my resque interval, how can I accomplish that with a resque.rake file that looks like the following:

```
# any chance to put that "Interval=0.1" in here?
task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end

task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"
```

does heroku even pay attention to the interval? (as it takes ages, ca. 15 seconds right now, to recognize a job in the queue on heroku)
Thanks

(Setup: ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.0.1, heroku cedar stack, resque, hirefire-gem)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the game here, but INTERVAL looks like an environmental variable.

Should be able to do:

```
task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
  ENV['INTERVAL'] = 0.1
end

task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"
```

Comment: This is correct - in `resque\tasks.rb`, tasks are started using this method: `worker.work(ENV['INTERVAL'] || 5)`